# Where are the Record Volume Controls in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, audio

Windows XP (and previous versions) had a Record Volume Control panel that could be used to select between music inputs (Stereo Mix, Wav, etc) and a microphone.   There doesn't seem to be an equivalent capability in Windows 7 .    Is there a third party application that provides this functionality?

Note:  the Windows XP Record Volume Control was accessed by doubleclicking the Speaker icon in the system try which displayed the (Listen) Volume Control.   In the menu there was a "properties" which gave you the option of displaying the RECORD Volume Control instead.
I used this capabiliy in Win XP to select the required inputs for an Internet Radio Station and now with Win 7, I can't do it any longer

Answer (score 2):

**Right click** the volume icon, and select `Recording devices`:

[image: Right click]

[image]

Comment: also right click in the blank space of that tab and select "show disabled devices", sometimes the driver has more features that windows hides. If there is a "Stereo Mix" for example, you can record streaming audio without special software.